# Autofac resolve within class library

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, class-library

I have a web forms application (myWebForms)

I have a class library project (myClassLibrary) that has a class called "myClass"

WebForms references myClassLibrary

I have added Autofac references to the web forms application, set the global asax to resolve "myClass" etc...

I can see that in my aspx code behind, the public property I added for AutoFac, is instantiated correctly by AutoFac.

All this is great so far, however, my actual project is a lot more complex than this, and what I need to do is have access to the resolved "myClass"
From within myClassLibrary

How do I achive this? (do I inject the container into myClass from the web forms project?, do I somehow reference the web forms global property, or do I build the container again within myClassLibrary?)

Comment: You can pass the object as a parameter in a constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33955886/6844481

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend checking out the Autofac documentation on web forms and quick starts. I think you may have a lot of questions answered by doing that, though I understand it's a lot. DI is complicated, and I'm afraid that providing just a "quick answer" here may lead you to an incorrect understanding of what's going on.

- [Autofac quick start](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html)
- [ASP.NET Web Forms Integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html)
- [Working example of web forms integration](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/WebFormsExample)

In general...

- You register types with Autofac that you want to inject. This includes all the types your web forms will need *as well as all the dependencies those types will need*.
- Autofac, via its integration, will resolve dependencies and put them in your web forms. If those objects *also* have dependencies (e.g., constructor parameters), then Autofac will *also* figure those out automatically and plug them in.

Say your web form needs a property called `IEmailSender`...

```cs
public IEmailSender EmailSender { get; set; }
```

Your email sender object may need some other dependency, like a network socket factory or something.

```cs
public EmailSender(ISocketFactory socketFactory)
```

You would register both of these in the container. **It doesn't matter which assembly they come from. You have to register them into the Autofac container for it to work.**

```cs
builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<IEmailSender>();
builder.RegisterType<TcpFactory>().As<ISocketFactory>();
```

When your web form gets the `IEmailSender`, Autofac will resolve the `TcpFactory` first, then provide that in the constructor of `EmailSender`, then that will be handed to your web form.

Again, a lot of this is covered in the docs and examples. While I realize there's a lot and it can be overwhelming, **I strongly urge you to walk through that info** because it can save you a lot of time and pain in the long run.

Comment: Thanks you, I have read up a lot now and managed to get Autofac working for a few areas, however, im still unsure of the best approach for this.  
the only option i see so far is to adjust the constructor to be "dumb", then can just inject that in.  And where I use to instantiate the object, i replace that with an "myObject.initiate(a,b)" method that i added to myObject (which replaces the constructor).
But i heard this is a code smell, and i also dont want to pass the contain from my webform to my library to allow resolve within library (which i heard also is a code smell)